# Returns null Location using Fused Location provider in android

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

I am using **Samsung gaylaxy Y SCH-1509**  android version **2.3**,Gingerbird

I am using a **Fused location provider** to fetch the coordinates , it works fine for me

it is same as that http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/08/fused-location-provider-in-android/

But the issue is after 2-3 days it stop giving me the location but after a day it again start giving me  the location (CONFUSED :X)

**Fused location provider uses** :- Wi-fi ,GPS, Network,Sensors Correct?

This Link Says [LocationClient getLastLocation() return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830047/locationclient-getlastlocation-return-null) you should have wifi gps enabled to fetch the coordinates

I have **enabled Wi-Fi ,GPS , Network**  but i still get a null location

Q1} What should be the **Google Apps** Settings ..?.

Q2) What can be the cause for it ? which coordiantes do get first while using **Fused** , how does it stop in getting the coordinates when it is working fine.

Comment: @raghave u got any solution same issue i am facing i had used fused location, network, gps, passive but no result

Comment: Tried restarting the device?