# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient) is not working 2nd time

Tags: android, location

Now I have a strange problem.
I have FusedLocationApi code.check it.I'm mentioning only related codes :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        Location mLastLocation;



        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            super.onStart();
        }


            @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .build();
            }




     mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                    double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

}    
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            super.onStop();

        }

            }
```

Now the problem is,this code is working perfectly for this activity.But when I'm writing the same code for other activity of the same project,`mLastLocation` is returning null and I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException.

only difference for that class is that there I'm implementing `OnMapReadyCallback` also.Does it make any difference?

I've read all the Q&A on this topic but not getting any help.
What's the mistake from my side?

Comment: you should do the call inside onCreate() method

Comment: Obviously I called inside onCreate(). I just didn't mention.Anyway,Check Again. I've edited

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441384/fusedlocationapi-getlastlocation-always-null

Answer (score 0):

onCreate method called first then followed by onStart. So in your case if mGoogleApiClient is not connected on create it will return null.move this code from onCreate to onStart

```
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
```

i will do something like this onStart

```
if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        // check for last location
    }else{
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        //check for last location
    }
```

Comment: it's calling the else block.but again mLastLocation is still null.

Comment: Check on a real device and for mashmellow and above devices you must  ask permission.

Comment: I do this in my phone,which is Lollipop.