# Google Api Client Location Updates Not Working and lastKnownLocation Is NULL After 2nd Attempt

Tags: android, geolocation, location, cllocationmanager, google-api-client

Good day.

I need to get location everytime the application is launching.
The location gathering is happening inside the fragment like so.

I am bulding client like this.

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mSharedHelper.showGreeting()) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

   @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

The `onConnected` callback is being triggered and I am doing the next.

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    try {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            failedLocate = true;
            hideGreetingCard();
        } else {
            failedLocate = false;
            //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
            currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            YahooWeather yahooWeather = YahooWeather.getInstance();
            yahooWeather.queryYahooWeatherByLatLon(getActivity(), currentLatitude, currentLongitude, this);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The issue is that the location variable is always null no matter what priority i have tried whatever i did nothing works, i got all of the permissions added inside manifest and requested at the runtime accordingly, and besides location variable being null, the `onLocationChanged` callback is never ever getting triggered but yet you can see that inside `onConnected` i am requesting the location update but nothing just simply works and no i do not need to use any kind of map to force any kind of simulation to happen i need just simply get the longitude and latitude of the user whenever the app is launched and this fragment is being shown thats much i want.
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441384/fusedlocationapi-getlastlocation-always-null

Comment: didn't you read my post? did not you see that i am saying I DO NOT NEED TO INVOKE ANY MAP TO UPDATE LOCATION!

Comment: that is not fixing the issue i have

Comment: actually this blog address your issue and how to handle it: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android. Look under "Logging the Current Location"

Comment: "The issue is that the location variable is always null no matter what priority i have tried whatever i did nothing works" -- devices do not continuously monitor for locations. `getLastKnownLocation()` might be used as an optmization, but that's it. "the onLocationChanged callback is never ever getting triggered but yet you can see that inside onConnected i am requesting the location update" -- make sure that you have locations enabled. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location/FusedNew) that uses the fused location API.

Comment: i have locations enabled as i am testing on the android 7.0 and request runtime permissions and i have gratned them manually

Comment: @VeneetReddy tried with that, not working...the callback never gets triggered

Comment: Check if `mSharedHelper.showGreeting()` is `true`

Comment: checked and it is true

Answer (score 0):

Location service is not ready immediately onConnected. Try adding a handler for postdelay action. Get the location 5 seconds after onConnected.

Comment: not a solution  as the callbacks is not getting triggered so this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of `getLastLocation`:

> Returns the best most recent location currently available.
>
> If a location is not available, which should happen very rarely, null
>   will be returned. The best accuracy available while respecting the
>   location permissions will be returned.

When a last location is not available you need to request one yourself like this:

Declare an instance variable:

```
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
```

And in `onConnected` do this (Don't forget to implement `LocationListener` on your component):

```
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            // Create the LocationRequest object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                    .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            // Location is already available
        }
    }
```

You'll receive the location in `onLocationChanged` callback:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Use the location
}
```

You should call `removeLocationUpdates` when you need to stop receiving location updates.

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

Since you need the location only once when the app is launched, you can call this in the `onLocationChanged` callback.

Comment: ok i will try this but before that i have 1 question, i do not need any precious longitude and latitude so the simplies network provide will be fully perfect as i need precious around the CITY and not street or meteres, so the hugest even drift will not give an issue, basically i am saying that i have seen that you are using HIGH_ACCURACY , so can i use the POWER_LOW mode isntead of HIGH_ACCURACY and it will work same way? as the high accuracy will require GPS and i do not want any GPS to be invoked as the network is fairly enough

Comment: Yeah it should work the same way, but with lesser accuracy.

Comment: perfect, testing it now

Comment: damn this not working....neither with high accuracy nor with no power the damned onLocationChanged callback is simply not getting triggered i dont know what the hell is wrong wiht this