# Device gets the location, but it returns 'null'

Tags: java, android, fusedlocationproviderapi

The Device Does fetch the location. The Problem is when I need to Access the Location, it `DeviceLocation.class` keeps returning a `null` value.

My `DeviceLocation` class

```
public class DeviceLocation{

    private static final String TAG = "DeviceLocation";
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 200;
    private static Location mLocation;
    private Context context;

    public DeviceLocation(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private void updateDeviceLocation() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 123);
            }
            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null){
                    mLocation = location;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Device Location is: " + mLocation.getLatitude() + ", " + mLocation.getLongitude()); //// ---> THIS WORKS
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error trying to get last Location");
            }
        });
    }

    public void getDeviceLocation(){
        updateDeviceLocation();
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation() --> " + mLocation); // WHY DOES NOT THIS WORK!!! ---> WHY DOES THIS PRINT 'null'!!!!!!!!!!
    }
}
```

In my `MainActivity` I declared a new `DeviceLocation` object, and initialized it in the `onCreate()` Method. Then I call the `getDeviceLocation()` method of `DeviceLocatio` class.

MainActivity.class:

```
DeviceLocation deviceLoc;
```

onCreate() Method:

```
deviceLoc = new DeviceLocation(MainActivity.this);
deviceLoc.getDeviceLocation();
```

Comment: You need to pass context instead of Activity first. update and check this

Comment: Refer this .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441384/fusedlocationapi-getlastlocation-always-null