# How return value out of Listener

Tags: android, kotlin, listener

Good day. I'm having a problem that I want to declare the latitude coordinates to a variable and then can be reused. But when I try to Log.d the returned `current_latitude` on OnCreate() it's equal to 0.0

This is my code:

```
    private fun fetchLocation(): Pair<Double, Double>
    {
        val task = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
        var current_latitude: String = "0"
        var current_longitude: String =  "0"

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat
                .checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 101)

        }

        // if android succesfully get permission, get location coordinate and display it to snackbar
        task.addOnSuccessListener{
            if (it != null)
            {
                // display the coordinate we get to a snackbar
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "${it.latitude} ${it.longitude}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                // get coordinates
                val builder_lat = java.lang.StringBuilder()
                builder_lat.append("${it.latitude}")
                current_latitude = builder_lat.toString()

                val builder_lon = java.lang.StringBuilder()
                builder_lon.append("${it.longitude}")
                current_longitude = builder_lon.toString()

            }
        }
        Log.d("lat :", "${current_latitude}")
        Log.d("lat :", "${current_longitude}")

        return Pair(current_longitude.toDouble(), current_latitude.toDouble())
    }
```

I have tried using StringBuilder() to transfer the data out of listener but nothing worked. Can someone enlighten me?

I also have tried `current_latitude = it.latitude()` but also when try to Log it outside the onSuccessListener, the variable become 0.

Comment: Reading the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) will help you understand the problem. You need to rethink how you structure your code, because you cannot directly return a latitude / longitude from this function.

Answer (score 0):

code inside the block executes at a different time than your function. You can print value by calling Log inside the block:

```
    task.addOnSuccessListener{
        if (it != null)
        {
            // display the coordinate we get to a snackbar
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "${it.latitude} ${it.longitude}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            // get coordinates
            val builder_lat = java.lang.StringBuilder()
            builder_lat.append("${it.latitude}")
            current_latitude = builder_lat.toString()

            val builder_lon = java.lang.StringBuilder()
            builder_lon.append("${it.longitude}")
            current_longitude = builder_lon.toString()

            Log.d("lat :", "${current_latitude}")
            Log.d("lat :", "${current_longitude}")
        }
    }
```

Also, the code inside `.addOnSuccessListener` could pass with a big delay (and not in the same thread) or not even be called at all (when you will get `.addOnErrorListener` to track what is wrong).

Comment: So how do i get the long/lat out of the listener?

Comment: the question is not **how**, but **when**. If you have a function to do some work with that coordinates, you can call that function from inside the block, keeping in mind if you planning to update UI, the function needs to be called in the **Main** thread (if you are in the Activity class use `runOnUiThread {  //code that runs in main }`)

Comment: you can also check this example of how to properly get value from the Location Service with callback: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50051348/4977439

Comment: `addOnSuccessListener` 's lambda is already called on the main thread, so you shouldn't need `runOnUiThread` for this.