# fusedLocationClient.lastLocation returns null for Android studio API 32/31, but not for others

Tags: android, kotlin

With the exact same code, no location shows up for API 32/31, but everything is working for other APIs. I am not too sure whether this is an API issue or sth. I have added all the dependencies and permissions in the XML file, as well as the API key (which is also enabled), but apparently, my emulator still doesn't like that.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29854418/7093155 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50448772/7093155 if you are the first client to connect, fusedLocation.lastLocation is null if called immediately your app launches

Comment: @Robin I have seen that before, but how do I make sure that there is a gap between showing the map and retrieving the last location?