# Samsung Note 2 can't reach onLocationChanged()

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-location

It works on most devices except Galaxy Note 2. It connects to Google Client, but can't reach `onLocationChanged()` that implements `LocationListener`. Anyone has any idea what it causes and why only on this device?

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(lat) + "/" + String.valueOf(lng), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        serverUrl = "http://(my server)/offers?lat=" + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude())
                            + "&lng=" + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()) + "&distance=1";
        // save
        makeTag(serverUrl);

        // after getting location data - unregister listener
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mFusedLocationCallback);
        new GetBackgroundUpdate().execute();
    } else {
        // get data from server and update GridView
        new GetBackgroundUpdate().execute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_location_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }
/**
Location methods
*/
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
}

/**
* Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
*/
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // Provides a simple way of getting a device's location and is well suited for
    // applications that do not require a fine-grained location and that do not need location
    // updates. Gets the best and most recent location currently available, which may be null
    // in rare cases when a location is not available.
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mFusedLocationCallback);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
    // onConnectionFailed.
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());

    if (mResolvingError) {
        // Already attempting to resolve an error.
        return;
    } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mResolvingError = true;
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        // Show dialog using GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(String.valueOf(result.getErrorCode()))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        mResolvingError = true;
    }

    //new GetBackgroundUpdate().execute();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
    // attempt to re-establish the connection.
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your Logcat

Comment: what is line no 90 in DistanceFilter.java ?

Comment: address = server + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude())
                        + "&lng=" + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude())
                        + "&distance=" + distance;

Comment: you havent posted that code..please post the relevant codes too..

Comment: looks like `mLastLocation` is null when you reference it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:  From the line in your comment where the `NullPointerException` is happening, just ensure that `mLastLocation` is not null.

```
if (mLastLocation != null){
    address = server + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) + "&lng=" + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()) + "&distance=" + distance;
}
```

Another thing to note is that you should always ensure that `mGoogleApiClient` is not null and connected before using it.

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
  //..... use mGoogleApiClient.....
}
```

[See documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#isConnected())

You should also add a check to see if Google Play Services are available, as sometimes the version available on the device is below the version that you compile your app with.  There is a dialog that you can show if that is the case.

Below is how to check if Google Play Services are available.

```
private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Note that `getLastLocation()` has a high tendency to return null, so a good approach would be to register a location listener if you get a null value from the first call to `getLastLocation()`.
See this post:  [LocationClient getLastLocation() return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830047/locationclient-getlastlocation-return-null)

Here is a guide for how to register a `LocationListener`:

Creating a listener:

```
LocationCallback mFusedLocationCallback = new LocationCallback();
```

Class definition:

```
private class LocationCallback implements LocationListener {

        public LocationCallback() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                 mLastLocation = location;
                 lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                 lng = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());


             }
    };
```

Then just register the `LocationListener` :

```
  mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
  mLocationRequest.setInterval(minTime);
  mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(fastestTime);
  mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
  mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(distanceThreshold);

 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mFusedLocationCallback);
```

Edit:  You should wait for the API to be connected before you register for location callbacks, it should be something like this:

```
/**
 * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // Provides a simple way of getting a device's location and is well suited for
    // applications that do not require a fine-grained location and that do not need location
    // updates. Gets the best and most recent location currently available, which may be null
    // in rare cases when a location is not available.
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        lng = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_location_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


     mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
     mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
     mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);
     mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mFusedLocationCallback);
}
```

Documentation:  [for requestLocationUpdates....](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)) and [LocationRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html).

One last thing, make sure that you have this in your AndroidManifest.xml inside the `application` tag:

```
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Should I use then if(mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mLastLocation != null) ? It would check everything at once

Comment: @jeand'arme It just depends on what you are doing.  You would not want to check all three at once before this line: `mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);`  Note that `getLastLocation()` has a high tendency to return null, so a better approach would be to register a location listener if you get a null value.  See this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830047/locationclient-getlastlocation-return-null

Comment: I will try using location listener because my app is fully location-dependent.

Comment: @jeand'arme I just updated the answer with a guide to set up a LocationListener, take a look.

Comment: Ok, I registered LocationListener in onConnected() and address that is based on mLocation is done in Callback and so far it works. If it won't crash on tests I will accept that answer since it helped me a lot :)

Comment: Yes, thank You. Thank god Google Location Api has this interface with onConnected() :) Cheers, man!

Comment: Ok, those Samsung phones are really up to something: they don't want to read location... Are they so modified in system terms that they just are different to use? Should I update this question or make a new one witch applied changes (since LogCat is not providing errors)?

Comment: @jeand'arme It works fine for me on my Samsung S4.  Do you have the latest version of Google Play Services on your Samsung devices?

Comment: @jeand'arme Also, make sure that the GoogleLocationAPI is connected before you call `requestLocationUpdates()` in order to register for location callbacks.  You can use the `onConnected()` callback in order to do that.  I just edited the answer, take a look at the edit at the bottom.

Comment: I tested it on Galaxy Note 2 emulator (provided by Genymotion) and it works great. I sent my app to my brother who got problems with it (he has Note 2) and I hope it will eventually be good now because otherwise I don't know what else could be the problem. One question: if I don't use fragments should I use "maintain state while resolving error" from this link https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html ? Thanks in advance, as always You deliver great help, Daniel :)

Comment: @jeand'arme Make sure that your brother has an updated version of Google Play Services.  He should get a prompt to upgrade from the `getErrorDialog()` call if he needs to upgrade.  Not sure about the maintain state thing, I'll check that out later when I have time.

Comment: Just went through everything we could on Skype. So, he has the latest Google Play Services. He still couldn't get his location - even wth GPS turned on. I'm looking for a solution how to get coarse location if fine location fails. Maybe that could be a workaround since it could happen to other users as well. I have updated question with recent code, maybe You'd like to take a look. Every method related to location is there.

Comment: I found something interesting on my brother phone now. To do thing based on location there is `(mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())` if statement. Interestingly, it can't locate itself, but apparently `GoogleApiClient` is not null and GoogleClientApi `isConnected` so now it's even more confusing because he can do things that normally shouldn't work (in that case location is defaulted to lat = 0 and lon = 0). How on earth it can be connected and yet not locate itself? #confused

Comment: @jeand'arme Sorry, just getting around to looking at this now.  I just looked at your updated code, and it looks good to me.  Whatever the problem is, I don't think it's your code.

Comment: Are there any workarounds like `if location is not obtained then get location through android.location.Location` ? I know this library is going to be deprecated, but could be this a reliable solution?

Comment: @jeand'arme can you also show where `mFusedLocationCallback` is defined?  The `onLocationChanged()` callback should be defined in this object.

Comment: sure, it's defined before `onCreate()` and it's like this: `private LocationCallback mFusedLocationCallback = new LocationCallback();` which is made as You described (class with LocationListener interface and empty constructor)

Comment: @jeand'arme Ok, just wanted to rule that out as the problem.  Does it get into the `onLocationChanged()` callback on your brother's device?

Comment: That will take me 2-3 hours since he's working right now, but as soon as I will get feedback from him - I will notify here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77825/discussion-between-daniel-nugent-and-jean-darme).

Comment: @jeand'arme can you post your full Activity class to a gist on gist.github.com?  I can run it on my Samsung S4 and see if I can find any issues.

Comment: @jeand'arme One more thing, can you add your build.gradle file and AndroidManifest.xml file to the question?

Comment: I sent it to You through mail :)

Comment: @jeand'arme I just updated the answer, add the `meta-data` tag for gms version, it might be the cause of things not working on your brother's device!

Comment: Okay, I got feedback from him. It doesn't reach onLocationChanged(), so it may be the problem here.

Comment: @jeand'arme  Yes, that would definitely be the problem.  The question now is what is the root cause of the problem that is preventing it from working correctly!