# How to check when LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() is not null?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I'm first checking if Location is ON using Android LocationServices.SettingsApi, if it's not I present standard location setting dialog using [Android documentation example](http://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#prompt). Later if user enables the Location I use *LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation()* to get current location. Here as below:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ENABLE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                                       .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                while (location == null) {
                    location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                        .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                }
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location not enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

*LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                            .getLastLocation()* takes around 1 second in my device to return non null value after enabling Location. The problem is that I'm using while statement till *LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                            .getLastLocation()* returns non null value. I think the way I'm doing this in UI Thread is not right. Maybe I can do it in background thread but what I want to know is there some better native way of doing.

Answer (score 0):

you could find the answer in this link :: already solved

[LocationClient getLastLocation() return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830047/locationclient-getlastlocation-return-null)

Comment: what are you saying "fused location wont work on pre-lollipop"...really :).. please check and its not a answer...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using background thread you can use [Handler.postDelayed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

```
if(location==null){
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        }
    }, 2000);//your waiting time.. I prefer 2 secs
}
```