# get Last Location is returning null object reference error

Tags: java, android, google-maps

hey guys my method to return my current(last known) location is killing my app.  My error logs aren't showing up, so the only think I can think of is that something is going on with the permissions/Location class.  I have it set to pull my location if it can, else return a pre stored LatLng. Please help! here's my code

```
public LatLng getLocation(GoogleApiClient client) {

    if(client == null){
        Log.d(null, "error:null client");
    }else{
        if( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Location mLastLocation = FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client);
            return new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLongitude(), mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        }else{
            Log.d(null, "error:permission fail");
        }
    }
return harrys;
}
```

and here is my error stack

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLongitude()' on a null object reference
>                                                              at com.example.kevin.memories.MapsActivity.getLocation(MapsActivity.java:251)
>                                                              at com.example.kevin.memories.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:93)
>                                                              at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                              at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
>                                                              at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
>                                                              at wv.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
>                                                              at maps.ag.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() is returning null; you should check for that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null object reference` means you're citing an object that doesn't exist yet. So this may mean that your call to that object came first before the object's initialization.
Try logging your `getLastLocation` if it was indeed able to fetch something.

Also check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830047/locationclient-getlastlocation-return-null) for additional answers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call getLastLocation(client) only after GoogleApiClient gets Connected.you can  check it by using client.isConnected() method or you can call it from onConnected method.