# Android: Display user location on Map Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, location, display

i am developing an app for my final year exam in android studio and i don't know how to show user location on MapFragment.

I've already do this but inside an activity, i need it inside the MapFragment.

This is my MapFragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap mMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mMapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());

        mMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }
}
```

In AndroidManifest i've requested the needed permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Did you try this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38473280/5444161]

Answer (score 0):

just add this

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}
```

to get current location on map.

Comment: I've tried but i need to request permission and i receive an error: MapFragment cannot be converted to context.

Comment: use

 MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.smartcity.MapFragment.onMapReady

Comment: i've tried but you just added: mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); and this works only if you require permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and i don't know how to implement them.

Comment: for Runtime permission check out this 
  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549561/how-to-check-grants-permissions-at-run-time]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

> In Gradle:

```
implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

In Fragment:

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private Location locationData;

    private static final long TIME_INTERVAL_GET_LOCATION = 1000 * 5; // 1 Minute
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 5000;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        TedPermission.with(getActivity())
                .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
                .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .check();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


    }

    PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted() {

            // Create the LocationRequest object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(TIME_INTERVAL_GET_LOCATION)    // 3 seconds, in milliseconds
                    .setFastestInterval(TIME_INTERVAL_GET_LOCATION); // 1 second, in milliseconds


            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                locationChecker(mGoogleApiClient, getActivity());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }


        FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                locationData = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Latitude: " + locationData.getLatitude() + ", Longitude: " + locationData.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.w("==>UpdateLocation<==", "" + String.format("%.6f", locationData.getLatitude()) + "," + String.format("%.6f", locationData.getLongitude()));

                if (locationData != null) {

                    LatLng point = new LatLng(locationData.getLatitude(), locationData.getLongitude());

                    mMap.clear();

                    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Your Current Location"));
                    //marker.showInfoWindow();

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(point).zoom(16).build();
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                }

            }
        }, null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        if (connectionResult.hasResolution() && getActivity() instanceof Activity) {
            try {
                Activity activity = (Activity) getActivity();
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }

    }

    public void locationChecker(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient, final Activity activity) {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(activity, 1000);

                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //Log.w("==>UpdateLocation<==", "" + String.format("%.6f", location.getLatitude()) + "," + String.format("%.6f", location.getLongitude()));
        //locationData = location;
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Latitude: " + locationData.getLatitude() + ", Longitude: " + locationData.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        //mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);



    }
}
```

> In Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E9EFF7"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
        android:name="your_packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your_packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<application
...

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_your_key"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Comment: Thank you, the code it's working but doesn't help me :D. I want to display the user live location, if the user walk or something ... the location should change.

Comment: @mateid, Ok i update my answer with set updated live location on map

Comment: Now i receive this error  :java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartcity/com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation

Comment: I have deleted this part from Manifest:    <permission
        android:name="your_packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />      Because with that permission i wasn't able to access "Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

Comment: @mateid, For TedPermissionActivity issue, you need add `implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'` Gradle

Comment: it's already added, i've read that is a bug with with appcompat higher than 26.1 ... so i've put it to 26.1 but the same issue