# GoogleApiClient parameter is required (Getting current location inside asynctask)

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a method with an asynctask inside.

```
 public void getNearest(){
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects){
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                        mGoogleApiClient);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            Collections.sort(marker, new Comparator<Location>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Location a, Location b) {
                    Location locationA = new Location("point A");
                    Location locationB = new Location("point B");
                    float distanceOne = mLastLocation.distanceTo(locationA);
                    float distanceTwo = mLastLocation.distanceTo(locationB);
                    return Float.compare(distanceOne, distanceTwo);
                }
            });
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

I want the `doInBackground` method to get the current location. This whole method is to be called in the `onCreate` method so I can have a variable for the current location. However, the app crashes and says that GoogleApiClient should be a parameter. It points to the `doInBackground` method. I am new to coding with the google maps api so I'm really having a hard time. Any help will be appreciated thank you very much!

buildGoogleApiClient():

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `buildGoogleApiClient` implementation?

Comment: Post updated sir!

Comment: Your `mGoogleApiClient` may not be connected when you call `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation`. You should call `getLastLocation` on the `onConnected` method. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986082/android-googlemaps-mylocation-permission/37986247#37986247) is a working example