# Fused location provider client returning null in reverse geocoding

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am developing an application in which user get their current location address.The code is seems fine to me but when i am running the app it gets struck in the single `Activity` and only showing `progress circle`. The getlastlocation() is returning null. I am using fused location provider client.

Address fetch service class

```
public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "FetchAddressIS";

    /**
     * The receiver where results are forwarded from this service.
     */
    private ResultReceiver mReceiver;

    /**
     * This constructor is required, and calls the super IntentService(String)
     * constructor with the name for a worker thread.
     */
    public FetchAddressIntentService() {
        // Use the TAG to name the worker thread.
        super(TAG);
    }

    /**
     * Tries to get the location address using a Geocoder. If successful, sends an address to a
     * result receiver. If unsuccessful, sends an error message instead.
     * Note: We define a {@link ResultReceiver} in * MainActivity to process content
     * sent from this service.
     *
     * This service calls this method from the default worker thread with the intent that started
     * the service. When this method returns, the service automatically stops.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String errorMessage = "";

        mReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);

        // Check if receiver was properly registered.
        if (mReceiver == null) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "No receiver received. There is nowhere to send the results.");
            return;
        }

        // Get the location passed to this service through an extra.
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);

        // Make sure that the location data was really sent over through an extra. If it wasn't,
        // send an error error message and return.
        if (location == null) {
            errorMessage = "no location data provided";
            Log.wtf(TAG, errorMessage);
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Errors could still arise from using the Geocoder (for example, if there is no
        // connectivity, or if the Geocoder is given illegal location data). Or, the Geocoder may
        // simply not have an address for a location. In all these cases, we communicate with the
        // receiver using a resultCode indicating failure. If an address is found, we use a
        // resultCode indicating success.

        // The Geocoder used in this sample. The Geocoder's responses are localized for the given
        // Locale, which represents a specific geographical or linguistic region. Locales are used
        // to alter the presentation of information such as numbers or dates to suit the conventions
        // in the region they describe.
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        // Address found using the Geocoder.
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Using getFromLocation() returns an array of Addresses for the area immediately
            // surroungetString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used)ding the given latitude and longitude. The results are a best guess and are
            // not guaranteed to be accurate.
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude(),
                    // In this sample, we get just a single address.
                    1);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            // Catch network or other I/O problems.
            errorMessage = "service not available";
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
            // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
            errorMessage ="invalid lat and  long" ;
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " +
                    "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +
                    ", Longitude = " + location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
        }

        // Handle case where no address was found.
        if (addresses == null || addresses.size()  == 0) {
            if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                errorMessage = "no address found";
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            }
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
        } else {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<>();

            // Fetch the address lines using {@code getAddressLine},
            // join them, and send them to the thread. The {@link android.location.address}
            // class provides other options for fetching address details that you may prefer
            // to use. Here are some examples:
            // getLocality() ("Mountain View", for example)
            // getAdminArea() ("CA", for example)
            // getPostalCode() ("94043", for example)
            // getCountryCode() ("US", for example)
            // getCountryName() ("United States", for example)
            for(int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                addressFragments.add(address.getSubLocality());
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "address found");
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
                    TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), addressFragments));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends a resultCode and message to the receiver.
     */
    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
        mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
    } 
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;

    private static final String ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY = "address-request-pending";
    private static final String LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY = "location-address";

    /**
     * Provides access to the Fused Location Provider API.
     */
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    private Location mLastLocation;

    /**
     * Tracks whether the user has requested an address. Becomes true when the user requests an
     * address and false when the address (or an error message) is delivered.
     */
    private boolean mAddressRequested;

    /**
     * The formatted location address.
     */
    private String mAddressOutput;

    /**
     * Receiver registered with this activity to get the response from FetchAddressIntentService.
     */
    private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;

    /**
     * Displays the location address.
     */

    private TextView selectManually;
    private TextView mLocationAddressTextView;

    /**
     * Visible while the address is being fetched.
     */
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    /**
     * Kicks off the request to fetch an address when pressed.
     */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location_fetch);

        mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());

        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar2);
        selectManually= findViewById(R.id.select_manually);

        // Set defaults, then update using values stored in the Bundle.
        mAddressRequested = false;
        mAddressOutput = "";
        updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        } else {
            getAddress();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        updateUIWidgets();
    }



    /**
     * Updates fields based on data stored in the bundle.
     */
    private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Check savedInstanceState to see if the address was previously requested.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY)) {
                mAddressRequested = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY);
            }
            // Check savedInstanceState to see if the location address string was previously found
            // and stored in the Bundle. If it was found, display the address string in the UI.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY)) {
                mAddressOutput = savedInstanceState.getString(LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("addressOutput", mAddressOutput);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs when user clicks the Fetch Address button.

    /**
     * Creates an intent, adds location data to it as an extra, and starts the intent service for
     * fetching an address.
     */
    private void startIntentService() {
        // Create an intent for passing to the intent service responsible for fetching the address.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);

        // Pass the result receiver as an extra to the service.
        intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);

        // Pass the location data as an extra to the service.
        intent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLastLocation);

        // Start the service. If the service isn't already running, it is instantiated and started
        // (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running. The
        // service kills itself automatically once all intents are processed.
        startService(intent);
}

    /**
     * Gets the address for the last known location.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    private void getAddress() {
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "onSuccess:null");
                            mAddressRequested=false;
                            updateUIWidgets();
                            return;
                        }

                        mLastLocation = location;

                        // Determine whether a Geocoder is available.
                        if (!Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.no_geocoder_available));
                            mAddressRequested=false;
                            updateUIWidgets();
                            return;
                        }

                        // If the user pressed the fetch address button before we had the location,
                        // this will be set to true indicating that we should kick off the intent
                        // service after fetching the location.
                        mAddressRequested=true;
                        if (mAddressRequested) {
                            startIntentService();
                            return;
                        }
                        updateUIWidgets();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "getLastLocation:onFailure", e);
                        mAddressRequested=false;
                        updateUIWidgets();
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Updates the address in the UI.
     */

    /**
     * Toggles the visibility of the progress bar. Enables or disables the Fetch Address button.
     */
    private void updateUIWidgets() {
        mAddressRequested = true;
        if (mAddressRequested) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            selectManually.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
        } else {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            selectManually.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows a toast with the given text.
     */
    private void showToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save whether the address has been requested.
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY, mAddressRequested);

        // Save the address string.
        savedInstanceState.putString(LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY, mAddressOutput);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * Receiver for data sent from FetchAddressIntentService.
     */
    private class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
        AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        /**
         * Receives data sent from FetchAddressIntentService and updates the UI in MainActivity.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

            // Display the address string or an error message sent from the intent service.
            mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LocationShow.class);
            intent.putExtra("addressOutput", mAddressOutput);
            startActivity(intent);

            // Show a toast message if an address was found.
            if (resultCode == Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
                showToast(getString(R.string.address_found));
            }
            // Reset. Enable the Fetch Address button and stop showing the progress bar.
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows a {@link Snackbar} using {@code text}.
     *
     * @param text The Snackbar text.
     */
    private void showSnackbar(final String text) {
        View container = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        if (container != null) {
            Snackbar.make(container, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows a {@link Snackbar}.
     *
     * @param mainTextStringId The id for the string resource for the Snackbar text.
     * @param actionStringId   The text of the action item.
     * @param listener         The listener associated with the Snackbar action.
     */
    private void showSnackbar(final int mainTextStringId, final int actionStringId,
                              View.OnClickListener listener) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                getString(mainTextStringId),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(getString(actionStringId), listener).show();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current state of the permissions needed.
     */
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");

            showSnackbar(R.string.permission_rationale, android.R.string.ok,
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main2Activity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    });

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main2Activity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted.
                getAddress();
            } else {
                // Permission denied.

                // Notify the user via a SnackBar that they have rejected a core permission for the
                // app, which makes the Activity useless. In a real app, core permissions would
                // typically be best requested during a welcome-screen flow.

                // Additionally, it is important to remember that a permission might have been
                // rejected without asking the user for permission (device policy or "Never ask
                // again" prompts). Therefore, a user interface affordance is typically implemented
                // when permissions are denied. Otherwise, your app could appear unresponsive to
                // touches or interactions which have required permissions.
                showSnackbar(R.string.permission_denied_explanation, R.string.settings,
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Location address show

```
public class LocationShow extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t1;
    String output,output2;
    private static final String ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY = "address-request-pending";
    private static final String LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY = "location-address";
    String mAddressOutput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t1=findViewById(R.id.place2);

        output = getIntent().getStringExtra("addressOutput");

        showAddress(output);
    }

    private void showAddress(String place) {

        t1.setText(place);
    }
}
```

These are the activities for getting address

This is the log

```
07-19 15:14:32.504 1219-1313/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-19 15:14:32.507 5369-5414/com.example.user.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-19 15:14:32.567 5369-5414/com.example.user.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-19 15:14:32.567 5369-5414/com.example.user.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-19 15:14:32.568 2713-2772/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
07-19 15:14:32.613 5369-5414/com.example.user.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7f47995a1d20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
07-19 15:14:32.623 5369-5414/com.example.user.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f47995a1d20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f478db47080)
07-19 15:14:32.746 2738-5125/com.google.android.gms I/Icing: Indexing 72BFAEF03056CDF63B46406CB190BC9702C5FE10 from com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
07-19 15:14:32.754 5369-5414/com.example.user.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f47995a1d20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f478db47080)
07-19 15:14:32.830 2738-5125/com.google.android.gms I/Icing: Indexing done 72BFAEF03056CDF63B46406CB190BC9702C5FE10
07-19 15:14:32.833 2738-5125/com.google.android.gms I/Icing: Indexing 81B472D5B60E335901521374F7E4943B2B43137C from com.google.android.gms
07-19 15:14:32.851 5369-5369/com.example.user.myapplication W/MainActivity: onSuccess:null
07-19 15:14:32.945 1909-1942/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.user.myapplication/.Main2Activity: +1s951ms
07-19 15:14:32.963 2738-5125/com.google.android.gms I/Icing: Indexing done 81B472D5B60E335901521374F7E4943B2B43137C
07-19 15:14:40.907 1909-1935/system_process W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
07-19 15:15:02.424 1219-1323/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 1619 syncs in 60s
07-19 15:15:56.618 2738-5417/com.google.android.gms I/EventLogChimeraService: Aggregate from 1531991756065 (log), 1531991756065 (data)
07-19 15:15:57.135 1909-3285/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
07-19 15:16:02.418 1219-1323/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 3092 syncs in 60s
```

Comment: Add some log statements at critical places or use the debugger to find out what is happening in detail.

Comment: I did, the getLastLocation() is returning null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LocationClient getLastLocation() return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830047/locationclient-getlastlocation-return-null)

Comment: I have seen it, it uses google api client which is deprecated for getting address, i am using fused location provider client